# How can I render one image over another in react-native?

Tags: react-native

[image]

I am practicing react native recently. I want that one image is always above another during animation. How can i do except for set the opacity?

Comment: e.g. use absolute positioning and opacity...

Comment: At beginning the flag is horizontal and I set the transfrom transform:[{rotate:spin}] which make it almost vertical. When the dish moves horizontally, the flag becomes horizontal using an animation. Can the flag always lie above the dish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest versions of react-native allow you to render inside the image tag. So you could put an `Image` tag for the recordPlayer inside an `Image` tag for the background. Try something like

```js
renderRecordPlayer = _ => (
 <Image style={styles.background}
   source={...} >
   <Image style={styles.recordPlayer}
     source={...} />
 </Image>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    // center the recordPlayer in the background Image
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    resizeMode: 'cover', // make sure background covers all of screen
  },
  {
    width: ...,
    height: ...,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
})
```